# Touch animation and OnItemClick in AdapterView

Tags: android, animation, ontouchlistener, onitemclicklistener, android-adapterview

I have a grid with items like this:

http://petromi.com/get/ba4a24f852.png

And I want to play animation for album cover when user touches it. I have created a class for this purpose:

```
class TouchAnimationHelper {
    ...

    public void setItemTouchAnimation(final View view) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                Log.d("Touch action: [%s]", action);

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    view.startAnimation(sDecAnimation);
                    return true;

                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        sIncAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                sIncAnimation.setAnimationListener(null);
                                view.performClick();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    view.startAnimation(sIncAnimation);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In adapter's `getView` method I call:

```
mTouchAnimationHelper.setItemTouchAnimation(view.findViewById(R.id.album_cover));
```

But the result is not completely what I want.
Animation is working when touch. But Grid's `onItemClick` is not called. It is called only when tap on text below the image. How can I make it call?

I've tried some solutions but they were not successfull:

1. Always return false in `onTouch`. But in that case there are no
   other touch actions proceed, out animation is not playing.
2. Pass additional parameters to `setItemTouchAnimation` and call
   `adapterView.performItemClick(view, position, id)` instead of
   `view.performClick()`. But in this case I got strange mess: raised
   event's item id didn't match clicked item id. I didn't still
   understand, why so.

Any other ideas?

Comment: have you checked http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29

Comment: Thanks. I tried something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537513/how-do-i-scroll-a-listview-after-requestdisallowintercepttouchevent-in-ontouchli. But I couldn't get it work

Answer (score 1):

OnTouch event in getview() return false instead of true.It works in my case.Hope it works for you..

Comment: I've mentioned this solution in my question and explained why it is not good enough.